# Click on DateField/ TextField / Radio/ ComboBox Ext.net and set other component to empty

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, extjs, ext.net

my question is not to get value after click the DateField/ TextField / Radio/ ComboBox.

I want to:
once click on the DateField and it can auto set other TextFields to empty.

Just like VB6 using onClick to set and how about in ext.net?
I tried onClick and onDirectClick but it failed.

aspx

```
<ext:DateField
    onclick= "ButtonClick";
/>
```

aspx.cs

```
protected void ButtonClick(object sender, DirectEventArgs e)
    {
        TextField1.Text = "";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using listeners if you want to efficiently do this in javascript or if you need to make more complicated decisions based on other logic you could use a DirectEvent in codebehind.  Both have similar syntax.

```
// pseudo code - fires off when the datefield selection occurs, 
// clears the text field and prevents the user from interacting with it
<ext:DateField Id="DateFieldClickOnceOnly" FieldLabel="Select A Date">
      <Listeners>
        <Select Handler="#{TextFieldOther1}.reset(); #{TextFieldOther1}.readOnly()" />
      </Listeners>
</ext:DateField>
```